# How to close html date picker programmatically using vanilla JS or CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, datepicker

Is it possible to close the browser's native HTML date picker using any vanilla JS methods? I'm referring to a native datetime picker like this one

[image]

gotten from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local#Handling_browser_support). I've tried different things and seen different suggestions including changing the `type` of the input field, setting `display: none` on the input field, replacing the input field (`node.outerHTML = node.outerHTML`), blurring the input field (`node.blur()`), setting its value to an empty string, and giving it `type="hidden"`. But none of these have worked. Whatever change I make to the element in the DOM, the native picker is unaffected and remains on the screen.

Any ideas for how to achieve this? The solution must work on Android. Thanks!

Comment: What’s the use case, why would you need to close this via script?

Comment: The part of the page that contains the date picker can change, and once it changes the user should not be able to pick a date anymore. With the picker overlaying the screen, the user won’t see the change happening underneath. Even if the user noticed the change underneath, it’s still not great UX.

Comment: Why is that kind of change happening, _while_ the user has the datepicker opened? _That’s_ not great UX to begin with, I would say.

Comment: It’s in a hybrid app. The user may be on the date picker and suddenly put the app in the background. Then get a notification from my app and tap the notification to re-enter my app. At that point I need to deep link to the source of the notification, which means closing the date picker and moving to where the user needs to be. The deep linking is the change, and it’s working. The problem is that the date picker continues to overlay the screen.